# Internal type U dependent on trait def

Tags: scala

I have a custom type, `Value`:

```
trait Value
object Value {
  case class BooleanValue(record: Boolean) extends Value
  case class LongValue(record: Long) extends Value
}
```

And a trait that knows how to get a `Value`, called `GetsValue`, given some input type `T`:

```
sealed trait GetsValue[T] { def apply(record: T): Option[Value] }
object GetsValue {
  trait GetsBooleanValue[T] extends GetsValue[T] { override def apply(record: T): Option[Value.BooleanValue] }
  trait GetsLongValue[T] extends GetsValue[T] { override def apply(record: T): Option[Value.LongValue] }
}
```

Notice that GetsValue is sealed, so users will only extend `GetsValue.GetsBooleanValue` or `GetsValue.GetsLongValue`.

```
trait Extractor[T] {
  def title: String
  def getsValue: GetsValue[T]
  def relatedValue[U]: U = ???  // question below
}
```

**What I want to achieve is the following:**

If `getsValue` is a `GetsValue.GetsBooleanValue[_]`, then return a `String` with the text "boo!" (i.e., `U` is of type `String`).

If `getsValue` is a `GetsValue.GetsLongValue[_]`, then return a `Double` with the value of 1.1 (i.e., `U` is of type `Double`).

Also note that I don't want to match on `getsValue`'s type `T`. I want to match irrespective of what its type `T` is.

I want to use type class / implicits if that makes sense. **Using `Either` is not an option for me.**

Comment: I don't think that will work, you could have a wrapped double/String though using Path dependant types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work:

First, modify `GetsValue` to add a type parameter that specifies the return type:

```
sealed trait GetsValue[T, V <: Value] { def apply(record: T): Option[V] }
object GetsValue {
  trait GetsBooleanValue[T] extends GetsValue[T, Value.BooleanValue] { }
  trait GetsLongValue[T] extends GetsValue[T, Value.LongValue] { }
}
```

Then a trait to correlate a type `V` to a value of `U`:

```
trait RelatedValue[V <: Value, U] {
  def get: U
}
```

And some implicit values of that trait:

```
object Extractor {
  implicit val boolRV = new RelatedValue[Value.BooleanValue, String] { def get = "boo!" }
  implicit val longRV = new RelatedValue[Value.LongValue, Double] { def get = 1.1 }
}
```

Then your Extractor trait can be:

```
trait Extractor[T] {
  type V <: Value
  type U
  def title: String
  def getsValue: GetsValue[T, V]
  def relatedValue(implicit rv: RelatedValue[V, U]): U = rv.get
}
```

An example implementation:

```
object Example extends Extractor[String] {
  type V = Value.BooleanValue
  type U = String
  def title = "Example"
  def getsValue = new GetsValue.GetsBooleanValue[String] {
    def apply(s: String) = None
  }
}

import Extractor._
println(Example.relatedValue)
```

Prints "boo!"